# what does systemd's [Manager] DumpCore option do?

Tags: linux, debian, security, systemd, dump

On my system (Debian 11), `/etc/systemd/system.conf` has a `DumpCore` option (boolean) in the `[Manager]` section:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See systemd-system.conf(5) for details.

[Manager]
#LogLevel=info
#LogTarget=journal-or-kmsg
#LogColor=yes
#LogLocation=no
#LogTime=no
#DumpCore=yes
...
```

I can't find any documentation about this option in systemd manpages:

- https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/systemd/systemd-system.conf.5.en.html
- https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/systemd-coredump/systemd-coredump.8.en.html
- https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/systemd-coredump/coredumpctl.1.en.html

What does this option do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option controls the behavior of systemd's "crash handler", i.e. the handler for SIGSEGV and related signals that would normally cause a coredump of PID 1 (the init process) should it crash for some reason.

As systemd runs as PID 1, it wants to avoid immediately exiting even in the case of a crash – the kernel immediately panic()s whenever the init process exits, which would make further debugging a bit difficult. For that reason it installs custom signal handler for all of the usual "crash" signals – SIGSEGV, SIGILL, SIGFPE, SIGBUS, SIGQUIT, and SIGABRT.

This handler, found in [src/core/main.c:crash()](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v250/src/core/main.c#L229-L238), will fork and *manually* trigger a core dump in a sacrificial "child" process, while the main process permanently suspends operations instead of dying, so that the rest of the system would remain sort-of running and you could still attach a debugger to it.

(For comparison, the old Linux 'sysvinit' [does the same thing.](https://github.com/slicer69/sysvinit/blob/3.02/src/init.c#L704-L778))

The `DumpCore=` option here only controls whether the crash handler actually tries to create a core dump or not. In some situations it might be necessary to disable it, e.g. if the problem being investigated also affects the systemd-coredump subsystem as well, or if it's an embedded system which doesn't have any place to store dumps anyway.

---

As this is a systemd 'manager' option which defines whether coredumps should be *initiated*, it has nothing to do with the systemd-coredump handler that would only *receive* the dump.

The option is in fact mentioned in the [systemd-system.conf(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/systemd/systemd-system.conf.5.en.html) manual page:

```
LogColor=, LogLevel=, LogLocation=, LogTarget=, LogTime=, DumpCore=yes, 
CrashChangeVT=no, CrashShell=no, CrashReboot=no, ShowStatus=yes,
DefaultStandardOutput=journal, DefaultStandardError=inherit

    Configures various parameters of basic manager operation. These options
    may be overridden by the respective process and kernel command line arguments.
    See systemd(1) for details.
```

The linked manual page documents it in the [Kernel Command Line](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/systemd/systemd.1.en.html#KERNEL_COMMAND_LINE) section:

```
systemd.dump_core

    Takes a boolean argument or enables the option if specified without an
    argument. If enabled, the systemd manager (PID 1) dumps core when it
    crashes. Otherwise, no core dump is created. Defaults to enabled.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed answer. `/etc/systemd/system.conf` options like `CrashShell, DumpCore, ..` are indeed equivalent to kernel parameters documented in [systemd.1 manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/systemd/systemd.1.en.html#KERNEL_COMMAND_LINE), with a different case (PascalCase vs snake_case)